# AngularJS: How to disable default watchers while getting data over $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, scope

I am using $http.get to get auth and user details so that i can show username instead of the login button.

```
.directive("plunkerUserPane", ["collectionsManager", function(collectionsManager) {

  var getAuth = function($http) {
    $http.get('/user/auth').success(function(response) {
      if (response.isAuth) {
        return 'user.html';
      } else {
        return 'userPane.html';
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    template: '<div ng-include src="userPane.getTemplate()"></div>',
    controllerAs: "userPane",
    controller: ["$scope", "$http", "login", "visitor", function($scope, $http, login, visitor) {
      this.visitor = visitor;
      this.getTemplate = function() {
        var template = 'userPane.html';
        template = getAuth($http);
        return '/components/userPane/' + template;
      }
      this.showLoginWindow = function() {
        login.open();
      };
    }]
  };
}])
```

When ever the data is being received by the get request it is called again by the default watchers and the starts and infinite loop. How to disable them or any other way around to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making API calls on `scope` methods is not an ideal solution, since they will be evaluated multiple times because of `$digest` cycle. You can use `callbacks` or `promises` for this and can remove the `method` to make `http` request from template.

See below

**Callback**

```
.directive("plunkerUserPane", ["collectionsManager", function(collectionsManager) {

  var getAuth = function($http, cb) {
    $http.get('/user/auth').success(function(response) {
      if (response.isAuth) {
        cb('user.html');
      } else {
        cb('userPane.html');
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    template: '<div ng-include src="userPane.template"></div>',
    controllerAs: "userPane",
    controller: ["$scope", "$http", "login", "visitor", function($scope, $http, login, visitor) {
      var self = this;
      self.visitor = visitor;
      self.template = 'userPane.html';
      self.showLoginWindow = function() {
        login.open();
      };
      getAuth($http, function(template) {
        self.template = '/components/userPane/' + template;
      });
    }]
  };
}])
```

**OR**

**Promise**

```
.directive("plunkerUserPane", ["collectionsManager", function(collectionsManager) {

  var getAuth = function($http, cb) {
    return $http.get('/user/auth').then(function(response) {
      if (response.isAuth) {
        return 'user.html';
      } else {
        return 'userPane.html';
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    template: '<div ng-include src="userPane.template"></div>',
    controllerAs: "userPane",
    controller: ["$scope", "$http", "login", "visitor", function($scope, $http, login, visitor) {
      var self = this;
      self.visitor = visitor;
      self.template = 'userPane.html';
      self.showLoginWindow = function() {
        login.open();
      };
      getAuth($http).then(function(template) {
        self.template = '/components/userPane/' + template;
      });
    }]
  };
}])
```

*Please note the usage of Promise Chain in above solution*

Comment: Its almost perfect but it is throwing this error
`GET http://localhost:8080/userPane.html 404 (Not Found)`